# Problem with Weblogic Upgrade

Tags: xsd, weblogic, xml-namespaces, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g

I'm currently in the process of upgrading my WebLogic version from 10.0 to 10.3.3.
I did manage to successfully create a new 10.3 domain, but when I try to start it, I get the following error:

```
<Critical> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000362> <Server failed. Reason:
[Management:141266]Parsing Failure in config.xml: failed to load java
type corresponding to e=domain@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain>
```

Regardless to say, the server doesn't start.

I looked at my config.xml file and it looks harmless, the first few lines of it are as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<domain xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls/1.0/wls.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/1.0/domain.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/1.0/security.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/xacml http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/xacml/1.0/xacml.xsd" xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain" xmlns:sec="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security" xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

There is a namespace entry for the namespace given in the error message (default namespace - xmlns), but I don't have a clue why the config file can't be parsed.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

A [similar issue here](http://kr.forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1082556) turned out to be a permissions problem for the user starting weblogic.

Have you installed the new Weblogic server instance with a different user id? Can you check permissions?

Comment: I don't know, but turns out that uninstalling WebLogic and then reinstalling it (all with the same non-administrative user) solved the problem. Go Figure...